# Writing small numbers to CSV without "E-X"

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am wrtiing data to a csv file using the python csv modules write funciton. However, small numbers such as 0.0000123 are being written as "1.23E-5"

This is causing issues when reading data back in.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you writing them?

Comment: ... and how are you reading them back in?  What software are you using that isn't able to parse exponential notation?

Comment: @Barmar Using the python CSV module. And reading back using Pandas

Comment: Why is the exponential notation a problem? Isn't pandas able to parse it?

Comment: What kind of issue reading back in?

Answer (score 0):

When you save to csv you can specify the float format in pandas

```py
df.to_csv('file.csv', float_format='%.3f')
```

Comment: FYI: That will write the value 0.0000123 as `0.000`, which might be an undesirable loss of precision.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser obviously OP has to accept that tradeoff if they are not willing to use scientific notation and choose an acceptable number of decimals.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Still, loss of precision is a fact of life every time you are converting from decimal base 2 to base 10, even if you use scientific notation.

Comment: @OriYarden You will always have loss of precision, no matter what when you convert from base 2 IEEE-754 Into base 10 ASCII. For example the decimal number 0.3 has infinite digits in base 2 representation. There is nothing that Pandas can do about it. In your solution, `%s` will only call `str()` on the value.